# How to custom-tweak X resolution settings

Tags: x11, xorg, resolution

Or should I rather phrase the question: how to construct a custom mode. The story is: I am a proud owner of an old EIZO monitor (IPS, etc...) which has started to display this flaw of bad lines. I.e. It does not display around 10-15 vertical lines right on the right edge of the screen. The rest is fine, but since this is the place where some important information can hide, I was wondering if it would be possible to construct a modeline such that those additional lines are omitted, let's say a resolution of 1265x1024. How can one go about doing something like that (I am familiar with basic and intermediate xorg.conf concepts).